# Motoko Language Extension in VS Code not underlining Syntax Errors

Tags: blockchain, motoko, dfinity

Hello there and hopefully to some of the new and growing Motoko IC Blockchain devs out there.

Small thing, and just as the title describes. I've installed Motoko for VS Code from DFINITY and everything is great including the highlighting (based on Rust they say). I just can't seem to get the syntax error squigglies showing.

I've reached out on the Motoko official forum and tried the discord but no solution has worked yet...

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

you can press Ctrl + Shift + P and then type motoko in VS Code.

then you can select your working directory.

[image]

[image]

i hope you will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Solution from @chanaka worked for me by just doing **command + shift + p** on **mac**